# Wordpress main menu item appears out of nowhere for mobile version

Tags: wordpress

I've been asked to look at the main menu on luxmux.com,
This is a Wordpress website, it has full and mobile version and the menu is different for both. For full version the menu works well and shows all the items as per Wordpress Dashboard>>Appearance>>Menu.
For the mobile version however the menu adds a "- MENU -" item to the menu (to the very top). I've been asked to remove this item.

From what I see the menu is generated in header.php with this single line -

`<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu_id'=>'nav', 'theme_location'=>'main-navigation')); ?>`

Initially I thought that I can remove a single item by using exclude, as per this example - 
[wp_nav_menu exclude pages from menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16112513/wp-nav-menu-exclude-pages-from-menu)

However, the "- MENU -" item does not have a page ID.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that's happening is that Javascript is building the menu based on the main menu. Look at the selectnav.js file:

`view-source:http://www.luxmux.com/wp-content/themes/shootingstar/js/selectnav.js?ver=0.1`

Look into that file and you can see `label = o.label || "- MENU -",`

You'll have to know some JS to fix this issue.

Comment: Dear @disinfor, I have set the label to an empty string  -` label = o.label || "",` It solved my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Find the css identifier for the element (like a class or id) and just add the following css to any css file loaded by the admin section:

```
.whatever-class {
  display: none !important;
}
```